# Normalization and Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to implement a Neural Network classifier (using sklearn) and I read on multiple sites that for this type of classifier (multilayer perceptron) is usually better to normalize the dataset before the classification; I've tried the classification task with and without normalizing the dataset, and the accuracy is always equal or higher with the non-normalized dataset. I've also noticed that all the features of the dataset have a very similar probability distribution, centered at 0, and with similar variances. My question is: is the similarity in distribution of the features the reason why normalization doesn't improve (or even worsen) my classifier? Should I normalize even if this means reducing the accuracy of my classifier?

Comment: How are you normalising it? You may be using an inappropriate method. For example, you might be assuming Normality when the real data is heavy-tailed.

Comment: Normalizing your data generally shouldn't make things worse, so it sounds like this might instead be an issue with initial conditions for your weights. Otherwise, this question is impossible to answer without reproducible code.

Comment: Does your data have heavy-tails? As @AlexR. suggested it can be a problem how you initialize your weights. Usually go for something like He or Xavier initialization, depending on which activation function you use.